# Which joomla template is that?

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I am very keen to know how to find the Joomla template a website is using.

Can I find which Joomla template is used by [maxhealthcare.in](http://www.maxhealthcare.in/) ?

Comment: I guess you are right. Because I am trying to find it failed

Comment: well.. it is customized with base on Beez5 template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the template name you are looking for is Beez5

You can view it on the URL `http://www.maxhealthcare.in/templates/beez5/css/beez5.css` as after `templates` root, it comes the folder `beez5` so that would be the name you are looking for.

Follow [this link](http://demo16.joomler.net/using-joomla/extensions/templates/beez5.html) to go to the Templates page at [Joomler.Net](http://joomler.net)

**Please note that you will need to match the template version with your [Joomla](http://joomla.com) version.**

Comment: But while i am searching for the similar template over the net (searching beez5 joomla template) I can not find it

Comment: [Check this link](http://demo16.joomler.net/using-joomla/extensions/templates/beez5.html)

Comment: But this is not the template which is used by maxhealthcare website. Is it ? @Mee

Comment: @MohammadArif Yes. Of course that the template has been slightly modified which means that you will not get the same. Errm.. you can try using the same CSS but that's just rude >:D

Comment: you are right but is there any way to get the same css ? Actually I want the menu style like it expands in sub-menu. I am trying to find wide area sub menu over the net but can not find good tut.

Comment: @MohammadArif Errm.. so you are looking for a tutorial on how to do that menu and not the Joomla Template? Is that it? Their menu is a `Moo Menu` which you can get the extensions for your Joomla template by searching on google. I found few examples before posting this comment, so yeah, its pretty much `Moo Menu` as it can be seen as well on their CSS for the menu which calls `http://www.maxhealthcare.in/plugins/sl_menu/mega_moomenu/assets/css/opera.css` where you need `sl_menu/mega_moomenu`.

Comment: Thanks dear. I am designing the template but not in joomla that is why it was a question for me.

Comment: @MohammadArif I dont know if you can apply that to your template, but you find it out using that on a joomla site and then check what it requires, like if it is only css or has javascripts as well.

Comment: Ok. Do you work in codeigniter?

Comment: @MohammadArif No, I'm afraid I don't. Do you need help on that?